# LLVM - Atomic Ordering Unordered

Tags: llvm, atomic

I'm working on a library that heavily relies on bitwise operations, where the most important operate on shared memory. I was also having a look at LLVM's atomic ordering documentation and noticed *unordered*, which seems to be even weaker than C/C++'s *relaxed* memory order. I have several questions about it:

- What are the differences between *unordered* and *relaxed*?
- Say I have an atomic bool, is it safe to mutate it via *unordered* **load/store**?
- Say I have an atomic bitmask, is it safe to mutate it via *unordered* **load/store**?
- Is it safe to mutate it via *unordered* **fetch_and/or/xor**?
- Is it safe to mutate it via *unordered* **swap**?
- Is it safe to mutate it via *unordered* **compare_and_swap**?

Comment: Unordered is "generate really fast code or else stop the compilation". It gets 10/10 for speed, 10/10 for always having a defined result, and 1/10 for simplicity and comprehensibility. Like the [JMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model#The_memory_model), which inspires it. An unordered lock is safe if you expect little enough of it, ie. if you don't expect that the assignments `a=true; b=42;` become visible to other threads at the same time or in order.

Comment: @arnt Note that ordinary Java fields (references, `int`...) are a lot weaker than C++ atomics. In particular they don't guarantee stability or consistency, only no invented values. I don't believe the Java guys are even agreeing with what they wrote down as a "spec" (aka approximation of their intuitions).

Comment: I know. That part of java is amazingly intricate and also amazingly assembly-like. A friend said, "it can be difficult to tell the difference between intentional JMM behaviour and a bug". But 10/10 for speed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: whatever your problem is, **unordered** is screamingly unlikely to be the solution !

The longer answer is...

---

...the [LLVM Language Reference Manual](https://releases.llvm.org/3.8.1/docs/LangRef.html?highlight=atomic#memory-model-for-concurrent-operations) says:

> **unordered**
>
> The set of values that can be read is governed by the *happens-before* partial order. A value cannot be read unless some operation wrote it. This is intended to provide a guarantee strong enough to model Java’s non-volatile shared variables. This ordering cannot be specified for *read-modify-write* operations; it is not strong enough to make them atomic in any interesting way.

The "A value cannot be read unless some operation wrote it." is fun !  What this means is that “speculative” writes are not allowed.  Say you have `if (y == 99) x = 0 ; else x = y+1 ;`: an optimizer could turn that into `x = y+1 ; if (y == 99) x = 0 ;` where the first write of `x` is the “speculative” one.  (I'm not saying that's a sensible or common optimization.  The point is that transformations which are perfectly OK from the perspective of a single thread, are not OK for atomics.)  The C/C++ standards have the same restriction: no “out-of-thin-air” values are allowed.

Elsewhere the LLVM [documentation](https://releases.llvm.org/3.8.1/docs/Atomics.html) describes **unordered** as loads/stores which complete without interruption from any other store -- so a load which reads two halves (say) of a value would *not* qualify if the two halves could be the result of two separate writes !

It seems **monotonic** is the local name for C/C++ `memory_order_relaxed`, and is described:

> **monotonic**
>
> In addition to the guarantees of unordered, there is a single total order for modifications by monotonic operations on each address. All modification orders must be compatible with the *happens-before* order.

Unlike **unordered**, with **monotonic** all threads will see writes to a given address in the same order.  This means that if thread 'a' writes '1' to a given location, and afterwards thread 'b' writes '2', then after that threads 'c' and 'd' must both read '2'.  (Hence the name.)

> There is no guarantee that the modification orders can be combined to a global total order for the whole program (and this often will not be possible).

This is the *relaxed* bit.

> The read in an atomic *read-modify-write* operation (`cmpxchg` and `atomicrmw`) reads the value in the modification order immediately before the value it writes.

Same like C/C++: *read-modify-write* cannot be interrupted by another write.

> If one atomic read happens before another atomic read of the same address, the later read must see the same value or a later value in the address’s modification order. This disallows reordering of monotonic (or stronger) operations on the same address.

It's monotonic, guys.

> If an address is written monotonic-ally by one thread, and other threads monotonic-ally read that address repeatedly, the other threads must eventually see the write.

So... there may be some latency between a write and reads, but that latency is finite (but may, I assume, not be the same for all threads).  The "eventually" is interesting.  The C11 standard says "Implementations should make atomic stores visible to atomic loads within a reasonable amount of time.", which is similar but with a more positive spin :-)

> This corresponds to the C++0x/C1x `memory_order_relaxed`.

So there you go.

---

You asked:

- *Say I have an atomic bool, is it safe to mutate it via unordered load/store?*
- *Say I have an atomic bitmask, is it safe to mutate it via unordered load/store?*

It rather depends on what you mean by *safe* :-(  With any atomic load of 'x' followed later by an atomic store of 'x', you have **no idea** how many other stores to 'x' there have been since the load.  But, the added joy of **unordered** is that it does not guarantee that all threads will see all writes to 'x' in the same order !

Your other questions are moot, because you cannot have **unordered** read-modify-write operations.

As a practical matter, your x86_64 guarantees that all writes are visible to all threads in the same order -- so all atomic operations are at the very least **monotonic**/`memory_order_relaxed` -- no `LOCK` prefixes and no `xFENCE` instructions are required, plain `MOV` to memory will do the trick.  In fact, better than that, plain `MOV` to/from memory gives `memory_order_release`/`memory_order_acquire`.

---

FWIW: you mention bit-wise operations.  I guess it's obvious that reading/writing a few bits is going to involve reading/writing some number of other bits as a side-effect.  Which adds to the fun.

My guess is that at a minimum you will need to be doing read-modify-write operations.  Again, on x86_64 this boils down to an instruction with a `LOCK` prefix, which is going to cost 10's of clocks -- how many 10's depends on the CPU and degree of contention.  Now, a `mutex` lock and unlock will each involve a `LOCK`ed, so it's generally worth replacing a mutex_lock/...do some reading and writing.../mutex_unlock sequence by an atomic read-modify-write(s) really only if it's just one read-modify-write.

The disadvantage of a mutex is, of course, that a thread can be "swapped out" while it holds the mutex :-(

A spin-lock (on x86_64) requires a `LOCK` to acquire but not to release... but the effect of being "swapped out" while holding a spin-lock is even worse :-(

Comment: Neither C nor C++ are MT-specified in any formal or even sound way. But yes, no speculative write allowed is the intent. But you can't have UB in such MT language, AFAIK. I tried to ask the Q about that and it got deleted like all my difficult disturbing Q.

Comment: OK @curiousguy, I'll bite: what Q is that ?

Comment: I asked if any single C++ program could avoid UB. Deleted. Later, how you can prove the correctness of an MT program. Closed. Also, my answer saying that the so called memory model of C++ was deleted. Another answer that say some Q was ill defined and unanswerable was deleted. Answers that say a Q is non answerable are delete as "very low quality". SO is nice answers oriented. Answers to Q about "why was X designed the Y way" that say "no reason" are deleted. Answers about "why is Z the rule" that say "it's the rule, period" are deleted.

Comment: Answers that criticize the quality of the C++ std, which is a complete failure as a spec from my (expert) POV (former member of the C++ committee speaking here, unlike almost all the ppl who came across me!) are deleted as rude. Yet I'm the one often insulted on that site. The mods almost always side w/ those you attack me, violating the site policy. And an answer using volatile to get more predictable overflow behavior was deleted with no refutation and insulting comments. It's clear mods don't care.

Comment: @curiousguy: speaking as a jobbing programmer: is it really controversial to suggest that the Standard is on the wrong side of incomprehensible ?  I have studied the C11/C18 standards, and concluded that when you know what they are supposed to mean, you may (with luck) be able to interpret what they say.  But I accept that I am not the intended audience.  I have to say that proving that an entire program avoids UB, or was provably correct do sound like large and possibly impossible tasks :-)  But program proving and such-like formal methods are too abstract for this humble engineer.

Comment: @ChrisHall in general, proving that program doesn't trigger UB is more or less equivalent to proving that it halts, which is undecidable ("in general" is the key here though).